# How to loop into multiple fieldname to get the files.path

Tags: node.js

I have Node.js app, served by express, with my frontend being made with React.js. My issue is i got to different fieldname for my images. Cover Photo and Avatar Photo. I'm having hard time to figure out how to loop into to different fieldname and get the path of the image. The result that i want is the backend will res.send(path of the image either avatar or cover or both of them).

```js
    // imageuploadroutes

    import express from 'express';
    const router = express.Router();
    import multer from 'multer';
    import path from 'path';
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.fieldname === 'coverPhoto') {
          cb(null, 'public/images/cover');
        } else {
          cb(null, 'public/images/avatar');
        }
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(
          null,
          `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
        );
      },
    });
    
    const upload = multer({
      storage,
      limits: {
        fileSize: '2mb',
      },
      fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (
          file.mimetype == 'image/png' ||
          file.mimetype == 'image/jpg' ||
          file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg'
        ) {
          cb(null, true);
        } else {
          cb(null, false);
          return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
        }
      },
    });
   
    
    router.post(
      '/user/profile',
      upload.fields([
        {
          name: 'coverPhoto',
          maxCount: 1,
        },
        {
          name: 'avatarPhoto',
          maxCount: 1,
        },
      ]),
      function (req, res) {
    var file = req.files[Object.keys(req.files)[0]]; 
    console.log(file)
      }
    );
    
    export default router;
```

**Result**

```js
   [
     {
       fieldname: 'avatarPhoto',
       originalname: 'Screen Shot 2021-03-02 at 11.49.56 AM.png',
       encoding: '7bit',
       mimetype: 'image/png',
       destination: 'public/images/avatar',
       filename: 'avatarPhoto-1614704247624.png',
       path: 'public/images/avatar/avatarPhoto-1614704247624.png',
       size: 597941
     }
   ]
```

but the problem is I can't get the .path

Comment: Why can't you loop through the result to access the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is an array, you should iterate over it:

```
var file = req.files[Object.keys(req.files)[0]]; 
console.log(file);
file.forEach(fileData => {
   console.log(fileData.path);
})
```

Comment: I used your code to send the filedata.path to frontend but right now i'm having issue on how to set the two filedata.path to be come the useState of the coverphoto and avatarphoto.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a new question on this platform, and I will definitely help you out.

Comment: Okies, Thank you so much sir. I will post it now!